# Bash script to list all processes in the foreground process group of a terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I write a bash script to print out the PIDs of all processes in the **foreground process group** of a given terminal (which is different from the one in which I run the script)? I know that the C function `tcgetpgrp` can do the job, but I am wondering if there exist any command line utilities that can do this more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the pids of all processes in the foreground process group of `pts/29`, you can do (on linux):

```
ps ao stat=,pid=,tty=  | awk '$1 ~ /\+/ && $3 ~ /pts\/29/{ print $2}'
```

`ps` is often different, and I am uncertain of the portability of that solution.

Comment: Thanks. I think there should be a `\ ` before `+`. Could you edit your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pgrep`'s `-t` flag, which enables you to list process using a given tty.

For example :

```
# on a first ssh session, which gets pts/0 :
sleep 10


# on a second ssh session :
pgrep -t "pts/0"
1234  # the first session's bash process
5678  # the first session's sleep process
```